# save file in Lotus Notes and full text search

Tags: database, full-text-search, lotus

Saving file in Lotus Notes have two problems:

1. the full-text search is slow and inefficient
2. the single database cannot be very big(related to the os file system).

How can i resolve the problem and Are there any replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lotus Notes/Domino (version 8.x) max file size for a single notes database is 64 Gb. I work with Lotus Notes/Domino for 17 years, and I did not meet the db size limit in my projects. Just split your project to different databases, according to its functional purpose.

If you want to store **very big files**, seems that you should choose a different platform. Lotus Notes is not a suitable tool in this case.

Regarding full-text search, if you setup the immediate indexing, then Domino server will index all new information added to the database as soon as possible. In my experience for small amount of data the indexing worked immediately, for big files it took one-two minutes.

The search itself works fast and I did not notice any slow behaviour on a hardware server that meets the Lotus Domino software requirements.

Comment: Our users usually save pictures or pdf files in lotus ,so it easily reach to 64G. In `different databases`,how to search?

Comment: @AlexYean if your users attach files to the database, consider using [Domino Attachment and Object Service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-green/). Regarding searching - please clarify, what kind of problem did you get? On my experience, if all databases that participate in multi-database search are indexed, then search works properly and quite fast.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `multi-database search`,i will try.

Comment: In lotus,all databases with full-text-search is appropriate?The database without full-text-search can not quickly be searched?

Comment: also check this [Domino help article](http://w3.kirkkonummi.fi/doc/helpadmn.nsf/1bce3bc9bebd3a848525619e00767b22/9e5ef9700d9bbb27c225654e006101c4?OpenDocument)

Comment: If a database is not indexed, then search works much slower. If you want a database contents to be searched, create full text index for the database. And please clarify your question "In lotus,all databases have full-text search is appropriate?", I did not understand it. You can create full text index for any lotus notes database.

Comment: In my experience,we carefully create full-text-search,because it will affect the server performance and take up a lot of space.

Comment: Indexing takes time for the first time, then index is being updated, not rebuilt. And it takes much less time. Regarding space - you are right, full text index takes the big amount of disk space and it should not be a problem. Disk space is not an expensive thing now.